# GraphDB - Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

How can I create relationship in already-created node like `T97` and `A02`?

I tried below query but it did not work and I received this warning: "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns."

```
match (a: KL {name:'T97D'}),(j:JCL {name:'A02D'})
with j,a
create (v_zt30_PT97D)-[:DEPEND_ON ]->(v_zt30_PA02D)

match (a: KL {name:'T97D'}),(j:JCL {name:'A02D'})
with j,a
create (v_zt30_PT97D)-[:DEPEND_ON ]->(v_zt30_PA02D)
```

Comment: "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns." is only a warning. It is not an error. What exactly did not work "correctly"?

Answer (score 0):

"This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns." is only a warning, not an error.

I think your real issue is very different. Your `CREATE` clauses are not even using the 2 nodes found by your `MATCH` clauses.

You probably meant to do something like this instead:

```
MATCH (a: KL {name:'T97D'}), (j:JCL {name:'A02D'})
CREATE (a)-[:DEPEND_ON]->(j)
```

By the way, in this case, a cartesian product is unavoidable. But you may want to create appropriate [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) to make the `MATCH` faster.